# Parsing psiblast output using Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I just ran psiblast on the command line and saved the result in my_output.xml. I am now trying to parse the xml file using Biopython so that I can iterate over the results generated in each psiblast round, but this is giving me issues. Here is my code:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

result_handle = open('my_output.xml', 'r')
blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)

for blast_record in blast_records:
    print blast_record.rounds
```

the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_psiblast_output.py", line 10, in <module>
    print blast_record.rounds
AttributeError: 'Blast' object has no attribute 'rounds'
```

What I want to do is:
for each query sequence, get all hits from the final psiblast iteration for that query.

Comment: What do you expect `blast_record.round` to be?

Comment: I made a typo in my code. It should have said "print blast_record.rounds" and not "print blast_record.round". I've edited my question. But either way, I still get an error. 
To answer your question: I expect blast_record.rounds to be an iterator of the rounds in each record.

Comment: Which version of BLAST are you running? Are you using the BLAST+ package?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are trying to parse output from the current NCBI Blast+ packages, rather than any of the legacy Blast packages (which are quite outdated now).

With that in mind, you should be using the `Bio.SearchIO` module.

```
from Bio import SearchIO

blast_records = SearchIO.parse('my_output.xml', 'blast-xml')

for blast_record in blast_records:
    print(blast_record.hits)
```

I also note that you are likely using Python 2.7, due to the lack of braces on the `print` statement. You REALLY should be using Python 3+ if at all possible. Biopython is dropping support for Python 2.7 as of 2020.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. Thanks for pointing me to SearchIO- I think I can figure it out from there. 
And yes, I have been procrastinating on switching to Python3. This can be where I start!

Comment: Hopefully it's a pretty painless switch, the benefits definitely outweigh the hassle. :)